# Django ModelManager causes DjangoModelFactory to return None

Tags: python, django

I have a django.Model object which needs to do some parameter processing when it get's initialized. So inside of it I made a ModelManager as the documentation suggests.

```
class ScheduledCourse(models.Model):
    """Represents a scheduled course that is/was bound to be held."""

    class ScheduledCourseManager(models.Manager):
        def create(self, *args, **kwargs):

            if not (template := kwargs.get("template")):
                raise ValueError("Template can not be empty")

            # If user did not specifiy values for these parameters, use the ones in the template
            for key in ["title", "description", "price"]:
                if not kwargs.get(key):
                    kwargs.update({key: getattr(template, key)})

            super().create(*args, **kwargs)
```

This works fine, I've tested it and I can create objects with the ScheduledCourse(...) call. When I tried however to make a factory for this object to use in my tests, then the factory returns None, without any error.

```
class ScheduledCourseFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = ScheduledCourse

    template = factory.SubFactory(CourseTemplateFactory)

    title = "Test title"
    description = "Test description"
    price = 1234.0
    start_date = datetime.today()
    end_date = datetime.today() + timedelta(days=1)
    signup_deadline = datetime.today() - timedelta(days=1)
    venue = "Test Venue"
    status = ScheduledCourse.Status.DRAFT
```

What is the cause for my factory returning none?

Answer (score 1):

Well this is ridiculous but I was missing the return keyword at the end of the create method.